# Match every word except those listed

Tags: regex, perl, cpu-word, match

My problem is that I need to match if a string contains any words besides the one(s) I list.

For example, I may have this approved list:

```
User1
User2
```

Here are two examples of what should match and what shouldn't.

Should match (because User3 is not approved):

```
User1
User2
User3
```

Shouldn't match (because every string listed is in the approved list):

```
User1
```

I have tried lookaround assertions, but they do not actually consume the letters as they try to match, so with a string like `"User1\r\nUser2"`, I get matches like `"ser1\r\n"`.  I want to know if there are any other words besides what I deem allowable.

I cannot use a programming language to do this; I am only allowed to hand a regular expression to the program. The language will be Perl.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does `/\b((?!(User1\b|User2\b)).+?)\b/` do what you're looking for?

`\b` means word break, i.e. the gap between a word and non-word character (zero-width).

`?!` signifies a negative lookahead assertion (also zero-width).

`.+?` is being used to catch anything not matching the excluded words.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If we want to capture the bad word, `\w+` or `.+?` would be better than `.+`, which will grab to the end of string. If we just want the boolean does-it-match test, I think just `/\b(?!(User1|User2)\b)\S/` would do it.

Comment: @AgileTillIDie Yes, after the edits, this appears to do exactly what I wanted.  I didn't think it possible.  Very nice.

Answer (score 2):

```
\b(?!(User1|User2))\w+\b
```

This should match any word not listed in the "|" delimited list

Comment: As aschepler commented, this doesn't match usernames that begin with `User1` or `User2`.

Answer (score 0):

```
/\b(?!User[12]\b)\w+/
```

will match any word (string of characters containing `a-zA-Z0-9_`) other than `User1` and `User2`.